# git log displays only a part of the commit messages

Tags: git, git-log, commit-message

The git log command displays only a part (upto a perticular limit of innitial characters ) of the original commit message. But I want to display the whole long log message on the console. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check it ?

> --log-size Include a line “log size ” in the output for each commit, where  is the length of that commit’s message in
>   bytes. Intended to speed up tools that read log messages from git log
>   output by allowing them to allocate space in advance.